# Why is squeezing a ketchup bottle on Shabbos not considered Dosh (Melechet Dash)?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, food, melacha-creative-work

Why is squeezing a ketchup bottle on Shabbos not considered Dosh (Melechet Dash)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"Dosh (threshing) is the fifth of the 11 agricultural melachos. It involves removing something edible from its natural casing." [OU.org](http://www.ou.org/torah/article/melacha5). I would hardly say that the ketchup bottle is its natural casing...

And in case you meant S'chitah: "S’chitah involves squeezing or wringing something out in order to extract a liquid" - which you're not doing here...

Comment: WOW! By 3 seconds. That might be a record.

Answer (score 11):

The prohibited labor category of "threshing" applies only to removing agricultural items from their natural container (such as threshing wheat, or squeezing juice from grapes); or wringing out absorbed liquid from something porous (such as a cotton cloth). The plastic container is not the "natural" container, and the ketchup is not currently absorbed in the bottle.

Comment: In fact, the halachic status Kli/utensil may itself nullify any considerations of Schita, despite its being porous or absorbent. See Sh"A O"C (320:17) re: sponge with a handle.